# How to improve SQL Server performance issue with hash match right outer join

Tags: sql-server, sqlperformance

I am new to performance issues. So I am not sure of what my approach should be.

This is the query that is taking over 7 minutes to run.

```
INSERT INTO SubscriberToEncounterMapping(PatientEncounterID, InsuranceSubscriberID)
    SELECT 
        PV.PatientVisitId AS PatientEncounterID, 
        InsSub.InsuranceSubscriberID 
    FROM 
        DB1.dbo.PatientVisit PV 
    JOIN 
        DB1.dbo.PatientVisitInsurance PVI ON PV.PatientVisitId = PVI.PatientVisitId
    JOIN
        DB1.dbo.PatientInsurance PatIns on PatIns.PatientInsuranceId = PVI.PatientInsuranceId
    JOIN
        DB1.dbo.PatientProfile PP On PP.PatientProfileId = PatIns.PatientProfileId 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        DB1.dbo.Guarantor G ON PatIns.PatientProfileId = G.PatientProfileId
    JOIN 
        Warehouse.dbo.InsuranceSubscriber InsSub ON InsSub.InsuranceCarriersID = PatIns.InsuranceCarriersId 
                        AND InsSub.OrderForClaims = PatIns.OrderForClaims
                        AND ((InsSub.GuarantorID = G.GuarantorId) OR (InsSub.GuarantorID IS NULL AND G.GuarantorId IS NULL)) 
    JOIN 
        Warehouse.dbo.Encounter E ON E.PatientEncounterID = PV.PatientVisitId
```

The execution plan states that there is a

> Hash Match Right Outer Join that Cost 89%

of the query.

[image]

There is not a right outer join in the query so I don't see where the problem is.

How can I make the query more efficient?

Here is the Hash Map Detail:
[image]

Comment: First of all: I don't see any table in your statement that uses the `InsSub` alias that you use in your `SELECT` list of columns ..... also: do you *really* need to join all those tables to get just these two pieces of information?

Comment: Can you show the detail of the hash match? What are the probes, what are the outputs? It isn't clear from the screen shot. I would guess that this predicate is causing your issues - `(InsSub.GuarantorID = G.GuarantorId) OR (InsSub.GuarantorID IS NULL AND G.GuarantorId IS NULL)`, you might wish to consider using two queries, and unioning the results together, often when you have `OR` predicates like this it results in a sub-optimal plan, and the two separate queries are better able to utilise indexes.

Comment: @GarethD Perhaps use an EXISTS in the where clause instead of using the those two predicates in the join?

Comment: Yes.  I need those joins.  The `InsSub` alias is used to get the insurance subscriber ID for the insertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment you could try splitting it into two queries, the first to match on `GuarantorID` and the second to match when it is `NULL` in `InsuranceSubscriber`, and in `Guarantor`, or if the record is missing completely from `Guarantor`:

```
INSERT INTO SubscriberToEncounterMapping(PatientEncounterID, InsuranceSubscriberID)
SELECT  PV.PatientVisitId AS PatientEncounterID, InsSub.InsuranceSubscriberID 
FROM    DB1.dbo.PatientVisit PV 
        JOIN DB1.dbo.PatientVisitInsurance PVI 
            ON PV.PatientVisitId = PVI.PatientVisitId
        JOIN DB1.dbo.PatientInsurance PatIns 
            ON PatIns.PatientInsuranceId = PVI.PatientInsuranceId
        JOIN DB1.dbo.PatientProfile PP 
            ON PP.PatientProfileId = PatIns.PatientProfileId 
        JOIN DB1.dbo.Guarantor G 
            ON PatIns.PatientProfileId = G.PatientProfileId
        JOIN  Warehouse.dbo.InsuranceSubscriber InsSub
            ON InsSub.InsuranceCarriersID = PatIns.InsuranceCarriersId 
            AND InsSub.OrderForClaims = PatIns.OrderForClaims
            AND InsSub.GuarantorID = G.GuarantorId
        JOIN Warehouse.dbo.Encounter E 
            ON E.PatientEncounterID = PV.PatientVisitId  
UNION ALL
SELECT  PV.PatientVisitId AS PatientEncounterID, InsSub.InsuranceSubscriberID 
FROM    DB1.dbo.PatientVisit PV 
        JOIN DB1.dbo.PatientVisitInsurance PVI 
            ON PV.PatientVisitId = PVI.PatientVisitId
        JOIN DB1.dbo.PatientInsurance PatIns 
            ON PatIns.PatientInsuranceId = PVI.PatientInsuranceId
        JOIN DB1.dbo.PatientProfile PP 
            ON PP.PatientProfileId = PatIns.PatientProfileId 
        JOIN  Warehouse.dbo.InsuranceSubscriber InsSub
            ON InsSub.InsuranceCarriersID = PatIns.InsuranceCarriersId 
            AND InsSub.OrderForClaims = PatIns.OrderForClaims
            AND InsSub.GuarantorID IS NULL
        JOIN Warehouse.dbo.Encounter E 
            ON E.PatientEncounterID = PV.PatientVisitId  
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    DB1.dbo.Guarantor G 
            WHERE   PatIns.PatientProfileId = G.PatientProfileId
            AND     InsSub.GuarantorID IS NOT NULL
        );
```

Comment: This is definitely faster by a lot!  But the records returned are not the same as original query. So I will have to tweek but this is definitely the way to go!.THANKS!

Answer (score -2):

I would re-order the joins based on the ability to reduce the number of records returned by each join.  Whichever join can reduce the number or records returned will increase efficiency.  Then perform the outer join.  Also, table locking can always be an issue so add with(nolock) to prevent records that are locked.

Perhaps something like this would work with a little tweaking.

```
INSERT INTO SubscriberToEncounterMapping (
    PatientEncounterID
    , InsuranceSubscriberID
    )
SELECT PV.PatientVisitId AS PatientEncounterID
    , InsSub.InsuranceSubscriberID
FROM DB1.dbo.PatientVisit PV WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN Warehouse.dbo.Encounter E WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON E.PatientEncounterID = PV.PatientVisitId
INNER JOIN DB1.dbo.PatientVisitInsurance PVI WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON PV.PatientVisitId = PVI.PatientVisitId
INNER JOIN DB1.dbo.PatientInsurance PatIns WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON PatIns.PatientInsuranceId = PVI.PatientInsuranceId
INNER JOIN DB1.dbo.PatientProfile PP WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON PP.PatientProfileId = PatIns.PatientProfileId
INNER JOIN Warehouse.dbo.InsuranceSubscriber InsSub WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON InsSub.InsuranceCarriersID = PatIns.InsuranceCarriersId
        AND InsSub.OrderForClaims = PatIns.OrderForClaims
LEFT JOIN DB1.dbo.Guarantor G WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON PatIns.PatientProfileId = G.PatientProfileId
        AND (
            (InsSub.GuarantorID = G.GuarantorId)
            OR (
                InsSub.GuarantorID IS NULL
                AND G.GuarantorId IS NULL
                )
            )
```

Comment: How does adding NOLOCK impact a hash join operator in the execution plan?

Comment: The order the joins are written in is irrelevent to the order they are executed in (unless you use `OPTION (FORCEORDER)`), so this would make no difference whatsoever. You may also wish to read [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/), it is not a magic performance fix and should be used with caution, usually by those that understand, and are aware of the risks.

Comment: I've found join order does matter and if you want trust the optimizer to do it's work for joins thats fine or optimize it yourself <a href='https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3201/how-join-order-can-affect-the-query-plan/'>Joins </a>.  Agreed no lock might not be needed or ideal but if something is locking it will make the execution faster by preventing a wait for the lock.  If it doesn't help remove them.  The hash match will always be there but reducing the record set size in the operation should help.